# Python create links from a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am trying to create a list of links, from a list of years, stored in a variable "newlink". When I call newlink I only ever get the last year in the list. Unless I just print(link+i) in the for loop without trying to store it in the variable. I know this is fundamental, but I cant find what I am missing.

```
list = ["2019" , "2020"]

link  = "http://link="

for i in list:
     newlink = (link+i)

print(newlink)
http://link=2020
```

Comment: You are overwriting the newlink in each pass of the loop. A list comprehension is probably better: `links =  [link+i for i in lst]` (Also don't use `list` as a variable name — you clobber the builtin when you do that).

Comment: Hint: `list` (you should not call it that, BTW) successfully represents multiple values, which is what you want `newlink` to do. Yes? What *type* is that value? What type of thing should you be making for `newlink`, therefore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to do the following

```
list = ["2019" , "2020"]
link  = "http://link="
newlinks = []
for i in list:
     newlinks.append(link+i)
print(newlinks)
```

['http://link=2019', 'http://link=2020']

P.S.: I changed variable name 'newlink' to 'newlinks' because it is a list.

Answer (score 1):

> *"I am trying to create a list of links, from a list of years"*

What you are doing is looping through the years and overwriting `newlink` every iteration thus after the loop it only retains the last `link + year`. You need to store these results to a list as you stated.

This can be done many ways although I suggest a list comprehension. *(also consider using more descriptive variable names and not using any builtin names)*

```
years = ["2019" , "2020"]
link  = "http://link="

new_links = [link + year for year in years]
```

Alternatively you could use `str.format` in the comprehension or even combine it with `map`

```
years = ["2019" , "2020"]
make_link  = "http://link={}".format

new_links = [make_link(year) for year in years]
#or
new_links = list(map(make_link, years))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting `newlink` in each iteration of the loop. Instead, create a list of links and populate it inside your loop.

Try:

```
years = ["2019" , "2020"]

link  = "http://link="
links = []
for i in years:
     links.append(link+i)

print(links) # output: ['http://link=2019', 'http://link=2020']
```

Answer (score 0):

you should define newlink as a list and append to it the values modified

```
years = ["2019" , "2020"]

link  = "http://link="

newlink = []
for i in list:
     newlink.append(years+i)
```

Answer (score 0):

you are overwriting the newlink variable and also you said that you need a list of links. So you need to do this

newlink = [ link+i for i in list]

using list comprehension you can achieve this in a single line.